# Probability of Runners

Tags: probability

> There are five men and five women in the race.
>
> a. What is the probability that either all the men finish before all the women, or all the women Finish before all the men?
>
> b. What is the probability that the fourth man to cross the finish line finishes before the second woman does?

For the first part of the question I think I did it correct I would just do ($\frac{1}{2}$)($\frac{4}{9}$)($\frac{3}{8}$)($\frac{2}{7}$)($\frac{1}{6}$)=$\frac{1}{252}$, since the probability keeps on going down for each ensuring gender having one less person to choose from.

The second part I am not sure how to do.  I know the probability of four men and a woman crossing first are ($\frac{1}{2}$)($\frac{4}{9}$)($\frac{3}{8}$)($\frac{2}{7}$)($\frac{5}{6}$)=$\frac{120}{6048}$ but I don't know how I would represent a man finishing before the second woman.

Comment: This is a really poor question if no assumptions are stated, e.g. that the runners finish in random order, or that the runners' times are independent, identically distributed random variables.

Comment: On the other hand, in real life with top-class runners at the given distance, the probability that all the men finish before all the women would be very close to $1$.

Comment: Exactly.  So why doesn't the OP merely state "two college track teams" or other balancing assumption?

Comment: I didn't make the question I just posted it as is, the assumption should be though that all are equally likely even though that would not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second, you can have four men finish in the first four places, which is just like you did for the first.  Otherwise, you can have three men and one woman in the first four places and a man in fifth.  There are four orders, but they have the same probability.  Compute one, again like you did the first part, and multiply by $4$.

Comment: So all I would be doing then is the first 4 probabilities instead of five for the men like this, (1)($\frac{4}{9}$)($\frac{3}{8}$)($\frac{2}{7}$) and then multiplying by 4.  Why are we multiplying by 4?

Comment: No.  For four men first you do what you did for five and got $\frac 1{252}$ but leave off the last factor $\frac 16$.  Then you do one woman, then four men.  That you multiply by $4$ because the woman can be in any of the first four places, not just first.

Comment: @Bram28 said that my first part was wrong and that it should have been 1 not $\frac{1}{2}$ so should it be 1 or $\frac{1}{2}$?  I understand what you are saying with the 4

Comment: Have you thought about why it should be $1?$. That doesn’t apply this time

Comment: When I orginally did the problem I said $\frac{1}{2}$ since it's 50 percent chance of male or female being first.  However, when he said 1 that also made sense since it could be male or female and depending on each one there is 100% chance it can be either or.  But so it should be $\frac{1}{2}$ then since we should assume it's either male or female.  Therefore ($\frac{1}{2}$)($\frac{4}{9}$)($\frac{3}{8}$)($\frac{2}{7}$)(4)=$\frac{96}{1008}$.  Does this look correct?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robert Israel in the Commnets that this is really poorly phrased problem in not saying what the assumptions are regarding the qualities of the runners ... but I'll run with your (in reality qute unlikely) assumption that each possible outcome is equally likely.

For the first, you should not start with $\frac{1}{2}$, but with $1$: it does not matter what gender the first finsher is, but after that you want to have the 4 people with the same gene of the first. So, the probability becomes $\frac{1}{126}$

This also makes sense from the following perspecive: there are ${{10} \choose 5}=252$ different ordering of males and females interspersed, and $2$ of them have all females or all males come first.